# Print a string and various integer variables C

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to learn C for a class next semester, and have a background in python.  I would like to print multiple arguments, both strings and various datatype objects using printf().  My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    short int x = 1;
    unsigned short int y = 2;

    printf("Short int x: %", x);
    printf("Unsigned short int y: %", y);
}
```

I am using Eclipse with a CDT plugin, no issues with binaries or anything.

I looked up the man page for printf() but was having some issues with the %. notation.  Could someone elaborate on printf's capabilities.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `printf("Short int x: %hd", x);` and `printf("Unsigned short int y: %hu", y);`

Comment: "printf format string" in google search line is a much faster way of finding a comprehensive answer as a first result. http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Comment: C "[printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)" uses a "format string", where each item to be printed has a "%" "format specifier".  Here is a good list of format specifiers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the C standard library:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    short int x = 1;
    unsigned short int y = 2;

    std::printf("Short int: %hi \n Unsigned short int: %hu \n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

The format string must correspond to the variable type, and also indicates how it should be formatted. `%hi` is for `short int`, `%i` for `int`, `%u` for `unsigned int`... See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Python, the `%` operator is used only as a format specifier, not as the separation between the string and the arguments.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    short int x = 1;
    unsigned short int y = 2;

    printf("Short int x: %d ", x);
}
```

Comment: So everything is kept w/in the quotations and based on the variable/character type you append a character after the '%' ?

Comment: @CyberOps17, That is correct. The arguments are always passed as normal function arguments, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The % symbol is used in the string as a place holder for where you would like to output the contents of your variable. The % symbol can be followed by different flags or specifiers to help format the output to your needs. Your printf line should look like this:

```
printf("Short int x: %d", x);
```

%d or %i indicates that the format of the variable "x" is a number. Here are some references for the printf() function:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/